# Install Node.js to install n to install Node.js?

Tags: node.js, npm, n

I have a problem understanding the use of [n](https://github.com/visionmedia/n). Basically, it is clear that it is a version manager for Node.js such as [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

But in contrast to nvm, which is basically a shell script, according to the documentation you are encouraged to use npm to install *n*:

```
$ npm install -g n
```

What I don't get is: For having `npm` at hand you need to install Node.js. Why would I install Node.js manually to use `npm` to then be able to install Node.js using n?

To put my question in other words: Why does n suggest installing using `npm`, if its main purpose is to install Node.js, which includes npm?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**tl; dr**

```sh
# Installs n and the latest LTS Node.js version to ~/n.
# For bash, ksh, zsh, modifies the respective user-specific shell-initialization file to
# define env. variable N_PREFIX and append $N_PREFIX/bin to the $PATH.
curl -L https://git.io/n-install | bash
```

---

I feel your pain. Installing Node.js to then install `n` to then manage Node.js installations is indeed a strange setup.

It would indeed be great to be able to install `n` by itself first.

I've created a **[project](https://github.com/mklement0/n-install) to support installation of `n` directly from GitHub**; the **only prerequisite beyond what `n` itself needs is `git`**.

Note that you must first remove any pre-existing `n` / Node.js versions.
The target directory, `~/n` by default, must either not yet exist or be empty.
For `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh`, the relevant shell initialization file (e.g., `~/.bashrc`) is automatically modified to define environment variable `N_PREFIX` and append `$N_PREFIX/bin` to the `$PATH`; for other shells, this must be done manually.

Aside from installing `n` directly from GitHub, it also installs helper scripts for updating `n` (`n-update`) and uninstalling it (`n-uninstall`).

Here are **working examples**; see the [n-install GitHub repo](https://github.com/mklement0/n-install) for details:

- Installation with confirmation prompt to confirm installing to default location `$HOME/n` and installing the latest LTS Node.js version:

  ```sh
  curl -L https://git.io/n-install | bash
  ```
- Automated installation to the default location, with subsequent installation of the latest LTS (long-term support) and latest-overall Node.js versions, as well as the latest 4.1.x Node.js version:

  ```sh
  curl -L https://git.io/n-install | bash -s -- -y lts latest 4.1
  ```
- Automated installation to the default location, *without* subsequent installation of a Node.js version:

  ```sh
  curl -L https://git.io/n-install | bash -s -- -y -
  ```
- Automated installation to custom location `~/util/n`, with subsequent installation of the latest LTS Node.js version:

  ```sh
  curl -L https://git.io/n-install | N_PREFIX=~/util/n bash -s -- -y
  ```

Comment: Does n-install let me install multiple versions of n? :D

Comment: @btx9000: Yes: you can install 2 version of `n` right next to each other to upgrade to `m`.

Answer (score 25):

If you prefer, you can install n from source:

```
cd /tmp
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/tj/n
cd n
sudo make install
```

Then you can install the latest stable version of node as follows:

```
n stable
```

Comment: I just want to add that if you get an error during "make install", you may have had installed it before. Then you should call "make uninstall" first.

Comment: `make install` fails with `cp: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/bin/n': Permission denied`. Maybe update the example to run with sudo?

Answer (score 16):

The *n* module was created for *convenience*.

For example, if you wanted to update your version of Node.js from v0.8.0 to v0.10.20, would you rather download a package, extract and compile? Or would you rather type `n 0.10.20` and have it instantly installed, while still retaining previous versions of Node for easy switching?

*n* suggests using *npm* to install it because *n* is a module. That is, *npm* is the easiest way to install it. Node modules have the functionality of being able to run in a shell when installed globally, so that function was utilized to make switching Node versions much easier.

Comment: Of course you are right that it's much more convenient to just type `n 0.10.20` and you're done, but why not use n for the initial install? This way, the very first install feels "special". E.g.: Is it guaranteed that n uses the same folders as the Node.js installer does?

Comment: Because *n* is a module, and using *npm* is simply the easiest way to install it. As for your second question, Node.js binaries are stored in *n*'s own directory, something like `/usr/local/n/versions`, otherwise you wouldn't be able to have multiple versions installed at the same time.

Comment: But the initial install isn't installed there - isn't that a problem? Please forgive me if this questions may be a little naive, but I just wonder why it is and I'm curious ;-)

Comment: Why would it be a problem if the initial install isn't there?

Comment: Maybe I have not yet understood how *n* works, but supposed I switch to another than the initially installed version: I assume that *n* then puts the new version to `/usr/local/bin`, hence it overwrites the previous one. And without installing the initial version *again*, I can not switch back. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure about the initial install, but for most cases `n prev` would just restore the previous version. **Edit:** It appears it also saves the initial install to `/usr/local/n/versions/.prev` when you first add a new version, as it does with any installation. Therefore `n prev` would also work in restoring the initial install.

Comment: Terminology quibble, because it confused me at first: _n_ (anything installed globally) is a _package_, not a _module_:  "Most npm packages are modules, because they are libraries that you load with require. However, there's no requirement that an npm package be a module! Some only contain an executable command-line interface, and don't provide a main field for use in Node programs." - https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-faq.html

Answer (score 3):

The README for `n` now has a longer section covering different [installation](https://github.com/tj/n#installation) approaches.

Like `nvm`, `n` is a bash script. `npm` is suggested as an easy way to install `n` *if* you already have `npm`, and then you can use `n` to change the Node.js version. But there are plenty of other approaches for a first install of Node.js. In brief and in no particular order...

You can install `n` using curl:

```
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tj/n/master/bin/n -o n
```

Or clone the `n` repo and install from there:

```
make install
```

Or use [n-install](https://github.com/mklement0/n-install):

```
curl -L https://git.io/n-install | bash
```

Or [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
brew install n
```

Or [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/):

```
port install n
```

(Disclaimer: I am the current maintainer of `n`.)

Answer (score 2):

You can also install `npm` separately from Node.JS; e.g.: on a system without Node.JS:

```
git clone https://github.com/npm/npm
cd npm
./configure
make
```

Reference: [NPM GitHub project](https://github.com/npm/npm)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, but have seen the light. 'n' is a handy tool and makes it simple to test different versions of node. Works great on Linux, but no matter how I try to install it on OS X (git clone, then npm install or using **user456584**'s recommended method), when I run it, I always get the same results of "*Error: no installed version*", even though it installs into

> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/n

and

> /usr/local/bin/n

Frustrating because I've found this tool to be so handy on Linux.

Comment: :) this could be a comment maybe.

Comment: Crooner, @fraxture: If you installed only by cloning `n`'s GitHub repo, then not finding any installed versions is expected: you must explicitly install them; e.g., with `n stable` to install the latest stable Node.js version. With neither `n` nor Node.js installed, you can also try `curl -L http://git.io/n-install | bash`, which includes installing the latest stable Node.js version - see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30967671/45375).

Comment: If it wasn't clear already, the error message is telling you that n has not yet installed any versions of Node, not that n itself hasn't been installed. Obviously, running `n` without having n installed (i.e. on your PATH) would give you a bash/ksh/zsh error message like `-bash: n: command not found` instead of the error message you see.

Answer (score 0):

If you have included your default node bin in the $PATH variable like this

```
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.5.0/bin:$PATH
```

then n will not be able to active other node versions. Remove this export from the path and then you can manage the currently active node version by n.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using n then you should use below command

```
$ sudo n latest
```

Comment: This does not look like an answer to OP's questions at all.